# Charting gender in IPython notebook using pandas or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, pandas, ipython

I have a Pandas dataframe with a Gender column which contains values M or F. I want to chart the count of all M and F as either a bar chart with 2 bars, or a pie chart with 2 wedges.

So far I've tried hist, but it errors out:

```
data['GENDER'].hist()
```

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Maybe I need to do a groupby?

Comment: what does data look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this - groupby/size to get the count of each gender, and use `.plot` vs `.hist` (which only makes sense for numerical data).

```
df.groupby('GENDER').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Thanks! Funny, I was trying df.groupby('GENDER').count().plot() before I saw your answer.